# How to go to the next line instead of printing \n?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm converting hexadecimal number to ASCII and printing it on the screen directly. But instead of going to next line I get '\n' on my output console. Could you please look into my code and tell me why I get this?

The hexadecimal values are stored inside a file called 'hexa'.

```
fin = open('hexa', 'r') 
hexlist = fin.readline().split(' ')
for i in hexlist:
    print(str(codecs.decode(i, 'hex')).strip("b'"), end='')
fin.close()
```

This is the output I get:

```
someRandomChanracters_._.\n\nOnly
```

But my expected output is:

```
someRandomChanracters_._.

Only
```

Thanks in advance for your replies.

**Edit 1:**
I think my question wasn't to the point. When converting from hexadecimal to ascii I come across these

```
a carriage return (0x0d) or a line feed (0x0a)
```

Instead of going to a new line the character '\n' is printed. Also when I come across single quotes(any special characters) they are printed in the following format:

```
"'"
"["hello"]" instead of [hello]
```

The contents of the text file is something like this:

```
D8 FF E0 FF 10 00 46 42 11 21 01 00 48 00 27 6E 2E 5F 2E 5F 6F 73 65
```

And my goal is to convert this hexadecimal file content to text format without any additional quotes or characters like '\n' '\t'

My question is how to overcome this?

Comment: Can you explain what `D8 FF E0 FF 10 00 46 42 11 21 01 00 48 00 27 6E 2E 5F 2E 5F 6F 73 65` would be in a string?

Comment: This is just a part of the large set of hexadecimals. Some represent an action so they have no ascii counterpart. `The first four pairs represent this(Ø ÿ à ÿ)`. Next pair has no ascii representation. And this `someRandomChanracters_._.\n\nOnly` is a part of the text after conversion of the hexadecimal numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a look at what your code actually does.

You take what's presumably a two-character string (let's say `0a`) and decode it to a single-byte byte array. Then you take the string representation of this (`str(...)`) which, in our example, is going to be `b'\n'`. Why? Well, a single byte with the value 10 (0x0a) is a newline character in ASCII, so Python shows it as `\n`, and the `b''` stuff is to show that it's a byte array. You then strip off the `b` and the `'`:s, and print what is left — a backslash and the letter `n`.

Rather than taking the string representation of the byte array (which is fairly useless for anything but debugging) you should be decoding it as a string. Something like this (untested) could work

```
for i in hexlist:
    print(codecs.decode(i, 'hex').decode('ascii'), end = '')
```

However, you'd be decoding one byte at a time, meaning that any multi-byte encoding (such as UTF-8) would not work. A better way would be to decode the entire string at once (assuming the string won't be extremely long):

```
print(bytes([int(x, 16) for x in hexlist]).decode('utf-8'))
```

(notice that the `for` loop has been moved inside the `print` call using a list comprehension).

Comment: What do you *want* to happen for invalid code sequences?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
with open('file1.txt','r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    data_list = [line.replace('\n', '') for line in data]

print(data_list)
```

---

**Output:**

```
['someRandomChanracters_._.', 'Only']
```

To print in newline,

```
print(*data_list, sep='\n')
or
# for i in data_list:
#     print(i)
-------------
# Output:
# someRandomChanracters_._.
# Only
```

Comment: No @shaik moeed by replacing '\n' we completely remove it from the output but that's not my goal. I want to go to a new line instead of printing '\n'.

Comment: @RishiNjr You can print in newline, by using `print` in `for-loop`. Is that what your expecting?

Comment: Sorry @Shaik for my ambiguous question I have edited it to be more specific

Answer (score 1):

When you get this kind of error you can you use string "split" function.

```
string_variable = "someRandomChanracters_._.\n\nOnly"

first_part = string_variable.split("\n\n")[0] #before \n\n
second_part = string_variable.split("\n\n")[1] #after \n\n
```

To print it the way you want:

```
print(first_part + "\n" + "\n" + second_part)
```

Comment: Sorry @eggrobot for my ambiguous question I have edited it to be more specific

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with open('hexa', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.split(' ')
        print(str(codecs.decode(line, 'hex')).strip("b'"), end='')
```

The `with` keyword will automatically close the file, even if something goes wrong.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Evan but I get _TypeError_ for your code. The `codecs.decode` doesn't allow list to be given in. I tried it with different for loops too one for splitting and another for printing but yet I get the same `'\n'` problem.

Comment: Can you post what the file looks like?

Comment: I posted it @Evan

Answer (score 0):

```
fin = open('hexa', 'r') 
hexlist = fin.readline().split(' ')
for i in hexlist:
    print(str(codecs.decode(i, 'hex')).strip("b'").replace('\n', ''), end='\n')
fin.close()
```

Comment: Sorry @sp1rs for my ambiguous question I have edited it to be more specific